# Why $(x-1)(x+1)\sim2(x-1)$ as $x\rightarrow 1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

My textbooks says that $(x-1)(x+1) \sim 2(x-1)$ as $x\rightarrow 1$, but I can't understand why.

Comment: What does $\sim$ mean?

Comment: It means that asymptotically as the function $(x-1)(x+1)$ approaches $x=1$, it is writable as $2(x-1)$.

Comment: If $x=1.01$ then $x-1=0.01, x+1=2.01$ and thus $(x-1)(x+1)=0.01\times 2.01=0.0201 \approx 0.02 =2\times 0.01= 2(x-1).$ You get similar results for any $x$ close to $1$.

Comment: Usually $f(x) \sim g(x) $ as $x\to a$ means that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$. Applying this in your case, you will find the answer.

Comment: Ok, solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first derivaation of $(x+1)(x-1)$ is $2x$. The value of $(x+1)(x-1)$ at $1$ is $0$ and the value of $2x$ at $1$ is $2$. So you can approximate the function linearly by the line $2x-2$. (The slope must be 2 and it must be equal to 0 at 1.) This is equal to $2(x-1)$.